# C# FiddlerCore API to capture data

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, fiddler

I am successfully using the FiddlerCore API in C# to intercept web responses from a particular web host and capture JSON data.

The FiddlerCore API seems to block any other web browsing in Chrome, IE, etc whilst my application is running and capturing data.  I understand that FiddlerCore creates a proxy to catch the traffic but wondered if it was possible to stop FiddlerCore from changing the LAN settings in my browser to direct traffic through a proxy?

I am currently Starting my Fiddler instance using the code below:

```
         Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8877, true, true);
```

And I intercept the data packets in my winforms app in the following event

```
         FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are starting up fiddler as a system proxy. To start it up without this you must not pass in FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy as one of the startup flags.

> FiddlerApplication.Startup(0,
>   FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default &
>   ~FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.RegisterAsSystemProxy);